# Local variables and tail call optimization

Tags: c++, scope, tail-recursion

I want to understand the implications of tail call optimization in C++. Consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

size_t mystrlen(const char* input, size_t size = 0){
    if(!*input){
        return size;
    }else{
        std::string str(input+1);
        return mystrlen(str.c_str(),size + 1);
    }
}

int main(void){
    std::cout << mystrlen("Foo") << std::endl; //3
}
```

`mystrlen` is a (useless) function that calculates the length of a provided C string. Consider the else-branch: A new `std::string` instance is created, and its internal buffer is used as input for the next call. If tail call optimization happens, and no new stack frames were created, wouldn't this lead to an error, because the local variable `str` would be destroyed before the next call takes place?

Comment: Tail call optimisation can't happen in this case, because the destructor needs to be called after the return.

Comment: My guess is (based on intuition and logic conclusions) that tail call optimization is not possible if the lifetime of a non-POD object contains the recursive return statement (i.e. it's constructed before, destructed after the return), because for each recursion another object lives. So space is required for all those objects... [Unless the compiler is able to detect that the object is not needed at all, like in this code ;)]

Comment: Don't rely on tail-call optimization to avoid stack overflow in your code.

Comment: What makes C++ different from many other languages, is its tendency to generate object code "corresponding to no source code". To some, it is a huge benefit, to others, tremendous drawback. In your case, the `return` statement is not the last in the execution flow. The last statement in the execution flow is the `}` that follows. What in your function looks like a tail call actually is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tail-call optimization under C++ falls under the as-if optimization freedom that C++ compilers have.

Barring a compiler with extremely detailed knowledge of `std::string` at a high level, what you did will block tail-call optimization, as the non-trivial destructor needs be called after the recursive call completes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you want to get rid of `std::string` in this case:

```
size_t mystrlen(const char* input, size_t size = 0) {
    if(!*input){
        return size;
    } else {
        return mystrlen(input + 1, size + 1);
    }
}
```

then you can see that your tail call optimisation will simply be:

```
size_t mystrlen(const char* input) {
    size_t size = 0;
    while (!*(input + size)) ++size;
    return size;
}
```

Comment: I used the `std::string` instance on purpose, as I wanted to know how local (non-trivial) variables affect the result of tail call optimization. I would have never written such a function otherwise ;)